# How to hide compiling message in Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile

The linux kernel I compile only prints message like:

```
CC  .....
LD [M] ....
```

How can I hide the compiling message printed out by make and output what I want? Where can I find the portion of code which does this in kernel Makefile?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In short, prepend '@'.

What the kernel makefiles do is rather more complicated, but it boils down to something like this:

```
%.o: %.c
    @echo [CC] $@
    @gcc -o $@ -c $<
```

Look at [the GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html#Echoing). GNU Make really is quite well documented, and if you're doing a lot of work with it it's worth the effort to read it through.

Comment: Uhm, so how is the compiling message from `@gcc -o $@ -c $<` suppressed? Is it because of `echo`? Edit: I read the page at your answer. Got it.

Comment: Make doesn't echo either command, but it still prints their output. So both the output from the gcc command (i.e. warnings/errors) and the output from echo will be show. So indeed, the output you see is not really produced by gcc but by echo instead.